# CloudWatch Events Metrics - DeadLetterInvocations

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-Monitoring-CloudWatch-Metrics.html) says:

Metric: DeadLetterInvocations
Description:

> Measures the number of times a rule’s target is not invoked in
> response to an event. This includes invocations that would result in
> triggering the same rule again, causing an infinite loop.
>
> Valid Dimensions: RuleName
>
> Units: Count

Can someone give a simple explanation of what the above description means in layman's terms.

Comment: I too find this confusing. "DeadLetterInvocations" implies the metric only increments when a message is sent to a DLQ, but everything else contradicts that. E.g. "InvocationsSentToDlq" implies the same to me, and the description for "DeadLetterInvocations" implies it records every failed invocation (regardless of if it was moved to DLQ). If you worked it out please share!

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused about dead letter invocation before,
correct explanation:

DeadLetterInvocations: Invocations that are failed temporarily and are being retried by the event rule itself. Only some events, such as those that fail due to a throttling or timeout error, are retried.

InvocationsSentToDlq: Permanently failed invocations sent to SQS DLqueue configured in the target.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the SQS DLQ, but rather is about events that are not being handled by an event because it would result in an infinite loop. Imagine setting up Bus A and Bus B, in which Bus A has a rule that forwards events to Bus B, and Bus B has a rule that forwards it back to Bus A. That scenario is where you will see this metric present.